# Is it possible to draw those 521 connections with no overlap?

Tags: graphviz

Consider the following graphviz file - is it possible to draw a graph for it? I experimented with `sfdp`, `K`, `repulsiveforce`, `overlap`, but I couldn't find any decent setup:

```
digraph {
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "snprintf"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "fdopen"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "mkdir"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "__errno_location"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "strerror"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "exit"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "printf"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "fprintf"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "fflush"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "maybe_delete_out_dir"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "open"
"setup_dirs_fds" -> "flock"
"afl_main" -> "setup_dirs_fds"
"afl_main" -> "sscanf"
"afl_main" -> "write_bitmap"
"afl_main" -> "get_qemu_argv"
"afl_main" -> "perform_dry_run"
"afl_main" -> "check_cpu_governor"
"afl_main" -> "fclose"
"afl_main" -> "get_cur_time"
"afl_main" -> "check_if_tty"
"afl_main" -> "destroy_queue"
"afl_main" -> "setup_signal_handlers"
"afl_main" -> "sleep"
"afl_main" -> "find_start_position"
"afl_main" -> "printf"
"afl_main" -> "check_crash_handling"
"afl_main" -> "get_core_count"
"afl_main" -> "fflush"
"afl_main" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"afl_main" -> "fix_up_sync"
"afl_main" -> "sync_fuzzers"
"afl_main" -> "write_stats_file"
"afl_main" -> "save_cmdline"
"afl_main" -> "detect_file_args"
"afl_main" -> "show_init_stats"
"afl_main" -> "access"
"afl_main" -> "setup_post"
"afl_main" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"afl_main" -> "exit"
"afl_main" -> "usage"
"afl_main" -> "getopt"
"afl_main" -> "setup_stdio_file"
"afl_main" -> "read_bitmap"
"afl_main" -> "destroy_extras"
"afl_main" -> "read_testcases"
"afl_main" -> "pivot_inputs"
"afl_main" -> "fix_up_banner"
"afl_main" -> "getenv"
"afl_main" -> "setup_shm"
"afl_main" -> "cull_queue"
"afl_main" -> "save_auto"
"afl_main" -> "show_stats"
"afl_main" -> "find_timeout"
"afl_main" -> "load_extras"
"afl_main" -> "load_auto"
"afl_main" -> "check_binary"
"afl_main" -> "check_asan_opts"
"afl_main" -> "fuzz_one"
"afl_main" -> "init_G"
"afl_main" -> "strcmp"
"write_bitmap" -> "snprintf"
"write_bitmap" -> "__errno_location"
"write_bitmap" -> "strerror"
"write_bitmap" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"write_bitmap" -> "exit"
"write_bitmap" -> "printf"
"write_bitmap" -> "close"
"write_bitmap" -> "fflush"
"write_bitmap" -> "open"
"write_bitmap" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "snprintf"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "memcpy"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "getenv"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "access"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "exit"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "printf"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "strrchr"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "DFL_ck_strdup"
"get_qemu_argv" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"perform_dry_run" -> "calibrate_case"
"perform_dry_run" -> "DFL_ck_alloc_nozero"
"perform_dry_run" -> "check_map_coverage"
"perform_dry_run" -> "__errno_location"
"perform_dry_run" -> "strerror"
"perform_dry_run" -> "getenv"
"perform_dry_run" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"perform_dry_run" -> "exit"
"perform_dry_run" -> "DMS"
"perform_dry_run" -> "printf"
"perform_dry_run" -> "close"
"perform_dry_run" -> "strrchr"
"perform_dry_run" -> "fflush"
"perform_dry_run" -> "open"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "strncmp"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "fscanf"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "fclose"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "__errno_location"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "strerror"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "getenv"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "exit"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "printf"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "fgets"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "fflush"
"check_cpu_governor" -> "fopen"
"nuke_resume_dir" -> "snprintf"
"nuke_resume_dir" -> "__errno_location"
"nuke_resume_dir" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"nuke_resume_dir" -> "exit"
"nuke_resume_dir" -> "delete_files"
"nuke_resume_dir" -> "printf"
"nuke_resume_dir" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"nuke_resume_dir" -> "rmdir"
"maybe_update_plot_file" -> "fflush"
"maybe_update_plot_file" -> "fprintf"
"maybe_update_plot_file" -> "get_cur_time"
"check_if_tty" -> "ioctl"
"check_if_tty" -> "__errno_location"
"check_if_tty" -> "printf"
"destroy_queue" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"setup_signal_handlers" -> "sigemptyset"
"setup_signal_handlers" -> "sigaction"
"save_if_interesting" -> "calibrate_case"
"save_if_interesting" -> "snprintf"
"save_if_interesting" -> "get_cur_time"
"save_if_interesting" -> "open"
"save_if_interesting" -> "has_new_bits"
"save_if_interesting" -> "add_to_queue"
"save_if_interesting" -> "__errno_location"
"save_if_interesting" -> "hash32"
"save_if_interesting" -> "write_crash_readme"
"save_if_interesting" -> "strerror"
"save_if_interesting" -> "simplify_trace"
"save_if_interesting" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"save_if_interesting" -> "exit"
"save_if_interesting" -> "printf"
"save_if_interesting" -> "close"
"save_if_interesting" -> "fflush"
"save_if_interesting" -> "describe_op"
"save_if_interesting" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"find_start_position" -> "strstr"
"find_start_position" -> "snprintf"
"find_start_position" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"find_start_position" -> "exit"
"find_start_position" -> "printf"
"find_start_position" -> "close"
"find_start_position" -> "atoi"
"find_start_position" -> "open"
"find_start_position" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"check_crash_handling" -> "close"
"check_crash_handling" -> "open"
"check_crash_handling" -> "printf"
"load_auto" -> "snprintf"
"load_auto" -> "maybe_add_auto"
"load_auto" -> "__errno_location"
"load_auto" -> "strerror"
"load_auto" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"load_auto" -> "exit"
"load_auto" -> "printf"
"load_auto" -> "close"
"load_auto" -> "fflush"
"load_auto" -> "open"
"load_auto" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"link_or_copy" -> "__errno_location"
"link_or_copy" -> "strerror"
"link_or_copy" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"link_or_copy" -> "link"
"link_or_copy" -> "printf"
"link_or_copy" -> "close"
"link_or_copy" -> "exit"
"link_or_copy" -> "fflush"
"link_or_copy" -> "open"
"link_or_copy" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"DFL_ck_alloc" -> "memset"
"DFL_ck_alloc" -> "DFL_ck_alloc_nozero"
"read_testcases" -> "strstr"
"read_testcases" -> "snprintf"
"read_testcases" -> "lstat"
"read_testcases" -> "add_to_queue"
"read_testcases" -> "__errno_location"
"read_testcases" -> "strerror"
"read_testcases" -> "free"
"read_testcases" -> "access"
"read_testcases" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"read_testcases" -> "exit"
"read_testcases" -> "DMS"
"read_testcases" -> "printf"
"read_testcases" -> "fflush"
"read_testcases" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"read_testcases" -> "scandir"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "snprintf"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "__errno_location"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "strerror"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "exit"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "printf"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "close"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "strrchr"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "fflush"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "unlink"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "open"
"mark_as_redundant" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"DFL_ck_realloc" -> "realloc"
"DFL_ck_realloc" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"DFL_ck_realloc" -> "abort"
"DFL_ck_realloc" -> "memset"
"DFL_ck_realloc" -> "printf"
"load_extras_file" -> "strchr"
"load_extras_file" -> "DMS"
"load_extras_file" -> "tolower"
"load_extras_file" -> "DFL_ck_realloc_block"
"load_extras_file" -> "fclose"
"load_extras_file" -> "__errno_location"
"load_extras_file" -> "strerror"
"load_extras_file" -> "__ctype_b_loc"
"load_extras_file" -> "atoi"
"load_extras_file" -> "exit"
"load_extras_file" -> "printf"
"load_extras_file" -> "fgets"
"load_extras_file" -> "fflush"
"load_extras_file" -> "fopen"
"load_extras_file" -> "strlen"
"load_extras_file" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "show_stats"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "fstat"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "sscanf"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "snprintf"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "save_if_interesting"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "write_to_testcase"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "__errno_location"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "strerror"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "readdir"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "closedir"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "opendir"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "exit"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "sprintf"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "printf"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "close"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "fflush"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "run_target"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "open"
"sync_fuzzers" -> "strcmp"
"write_stats_file" -> "snprintf"
"write_stats_file" -> "fdopen"
"write_stats_file" -> "fclose"
"write_stats_file" -> "__errno_location"
"write_stats_file" -> "strerror"
"write_stats_file" -> "get_cur_time"
"write_stats_file" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"write_stats_file" -> "exit"
"write_stats_file" -> "getpid"
"write_stats_file" -> "printf"
"write_stats_file" -> "fprintf"
"write_stats_file" -> "fflush"
"write_stats_file" -> "open"
"write_stats_file" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"check_binary" -> "strchr"
"check_binary" -> "strncmp"
"check_binary" -> "stat"
"check_binary" -> "snprintf"
"check_binary" -> "memcmp"
"check_binary" -> "__errno_location"
"check_binary" -> "strerror"
"check_binary" -> "memcpy"
"check_binary" -> "getenv"
"check_binary" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"check_binary" -> "exit"
"check_binary" -> "printf"
"check_binary" -> "close"
"check_binary" -> "fflush"
"check_binary" -> "DFL_ck_strdup"
"check_binary" -> "open"
"check_binary" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"detect_file_args" -> "strstr"
"detect_file_args" -> "snprintf"
"detect_file_args" -> "__errno_location"
"detect_file_args" -> "strerror"
"detect_file_args" -> "free"
"detect_file_args" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"detect_file_args" -> "exit"
"detect_file_args" -> "printf"
"detect_file_args" -> "fflush"
"detect_file_args" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"show_init_stats" -> "DMS"
"show_init_stats" -> "DI"
"show_init_stats" -> "printf"
"check_term_size" -> "ioctl"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "snprintf"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "__errno_location"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "strerror"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "exit"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "printf"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "close"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "strrchr"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "fflush"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "open"
"mark_as_det_done" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"setup_post" -> ""
"setup_post" -> "dlsym"
"setup_post" -> "getenv"
"setup_post" -> "exit"
"setup_post" -> "dlerror"
"setup_post" -> "printf"
"setup_post" -> "dlopen"
"DFL_ck_free" -> "abort"
"DFL_ck_free" -> "free"
"DFL_ck_free" -> "printf"
"add_to_queue" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"add_to_queue" -> "get_cur_time"
"usage" -> "exit"
"usage" -> "printf"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "snprintf"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "__errno_location"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "strerror"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "exit"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "printf"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "fflush"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "unlink"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "open"
"setup_stdio_file" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"describe_op" -> "strlen"
"describe_op" -> "sprintf"
"describe_op" -> "strcat"
"read_bitmap" -> "__errno_location"
"read_bitmap" -> "strerror"
"read_bitmap" -> "exit"
"read_bitmap" -> "printf"
"read_bitmap" -> "close"
"read_bitmap" -> "fflush"
"read_bitmap" -> "open"
"destroy_extras" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"fix_up_sync" -> "snprintf"
"fix_up_sync" -> "exit"
"fix_up_sync" -> "printf"
"fix_up_sync" -> "__ctype_b_loc"
"fix_up_sync" -> "strlen"
"fix_up_sync" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"save_cmdline" -> "strlen"
"save_cmdline" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"save_cmdline" -> "memcpy"
"DFL_ck_memdup_str" -> "malloc"
"DFL_ck_memdup_str" -> "abort"
"DFL_ck_memdup_str" -> "memcpy"
"DFL_ck_memdup_str" -> "printf"
"pivot_inputs" -> "strncmp"
"pivot_inputs" -> "strchr"
"pivot_inputs" -> "sscanf"
"pivot_inputs" -> "snprintf"
"pivot_inputs" -> "nuke_resume_dir"
"pivot_inputs" -> "mark_as_det_done"
"pivot_inputs" -> "strstr"
"pivot_inputs" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"pivot_inputs" -> "exit"
"pivot_inputs" -> "printf"
"pivot_inputs" -> "strrchr"
"pivot_inputs" -> "link_or_copy"
"pivot_inputs" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"fix_up_banner" -> "strrchr"
"fix_up_banner" -> "strlen"
"fix_up_banner" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"fix_up_banner" -> "sprintf"
"find_timeout" -> "strstr"
"find_timeout" -> "snprintf"
"find_timeout" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"find_timeout" -> "exit"
"find_timeout" -> "printf"
"find_timeout" -> "close"
"find_timeout" -> "atoi"
"find_timeout" -> "open"
"find_timeout" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"cull_queue" -> "mark_as_redundant"
"cull_queue" -> "memset"
"save_auto" -> "snprintf"
"save_auto" -> "__errno_location"
"save_auto" -> "strerror"
"save_auto" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"save_auto" -> "exit"
"save_auto" -> "printf"
"save_auto" -> "close"
"save_auto" -> "fflush"
"save_auto" -> "open"
"save_auto" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"show_stats" -> "get_runnable_processes"
"show_stats" -> "count_bits"
"show_stats" -> "memset"
"show_stats" -> "write_bitmap"
"show_stats" -> "write_stats_file"
"show_stats" -> "DI"
"show_stats" -> "DF"
"show_stats" -> "printf"
"show_stats" -> "check_term_size"
"show_stats" -> "maybe_update_plot_file"
"show_stats" -> "get_cur_time"
"show_stats" -> "strcat"
"show_stats" -> "DTD"
"show_stats" -> "strcpy"
"show_stats" -> "sprintf"
"show_stats" -> "count_non_255_bytes"
"show_stats" -> "save_auto"
"show_stats" -> "getenv"
"show_stats" -> "strlen"
"show_stats" -> "fflush"
"DFL_ck_alloc_nozero" -> "malloc"
"DFL_ck_alloc_nozero" -> "abort"
"DFL_ck_alloc_nozero" -> "printf"
"DFL_ck_realloc_block" -> "DFL_ck_realloc"
"DFL_ck_realloc_block" -> "abort"
"DFL_ck_realloc_block" -> "printf"
"write_crash_readme" -> "DMS"
"write_crash_readme" -> "snprintf"
"write_crash_readme" -> "fdopen"
"write_crash_readme" -> "fprintf"
"write_crash_readme" -> "fclose"
"write_crash_readme" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"write_crash_readme" -> "exit"
"write_crash_readme" -> "printf"
"write_crash_readme" -> "close"
"write_crash_readme" -> "open"
"write_crash_readme" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"check_map_coverage" -> "count_bytes"
"check_map_coverage" -> "printf"
"write_to_testcase" -> "lseek"
"write_to_testcase" -> "__errno_location"
"write_to_testcase" -> "strerror"
"write_to_testcase" -> "exit"
"write_to_testcase" -> "printf"
"write_to_testcase" -> "close"
"write_to_testcase" -> "ftruncate"
"write_to_testcase" -> "fflush"
"write_to_testcase" -> "unlink"
"write_to_testcase" -> "open"
"handle_timeout" -> "kill"
"load_extras" -> "strchr"
"load_extras" -> "load_extras_file"
"load_extras" -> "DMS"
"load_extras" -> "DFL_ck_realloc_block"
"load_extras" -> "snprintf"
"load_extras" -> "lstat"
"load_extras" -> "__errno_location"
"load_extras" -> "strerror"
"load_extras" -> "readdir"
"load_extras" -> "access"
"load_extras" -> "closedir"
"load_extras" -> "opendir"
"load_extras" -> "atoi"
"load_extras" -> "exit"
"load_extras" -> "printf"
"load_extras" -> "close"
"load_extras" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"load_extras" -> "fflush"
"load_extras" -> "open"
"load_extras" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"DFL_ck_strdup" -> "malloc"
"DFL_ck_strdup" -> "abort"
"DFL_ck_strdup" -> "strlen"
"DFL_ck_strdup" -> "memcpy"
"DFL_ck_strdup" -> "printf"
"DFL_ck_memdup" -> "malloc"
"DFL_ck_memdup" -> "abort"
"DFL_ck_memdup" -> "memcpy"
"DFL_ck_memdup" -> "printf"
"check_asan_opts" -> "exit"
"check_asan_opts" -> "printf"
"check_asan_opts" -> "strstr"
"check_asan_opts" -> "getenv"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "rename"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "unlink"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "time"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "snprintf"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "flock"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "fclose"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "fscanf"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "__errno_location"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "strerror"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "localtime"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "exit"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "delete_files"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "printf"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "fflush"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "fopen"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "open"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"maybe_delete_out_dir" -> "rmdir"
"handle_stop_sig" -> "kill"
"mark_as_variable" -> "snprintf"
"mark_as_variable" -> "__errno_location"
"mark_as_variable" -> "strerror"
"mark_as_variable" -> "symlink"
"mark_as_variable" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"mark_as_variable" -> "exit"
"mark_as_variable" -> "printf"
"mark_as_variable" -> "close"
"mark_as_variable" -> "strrchr"
"mark_as_variable" -> "fflush"
"mark_as_variable" -> "open"
"mark_as_variable" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
"delete_files" -> "strncmp"
"delete_files" -> "snprintf"
"delete_files" -> "__errno_location"
"delete_files" -> "strerror"
"delete_files" -> "readdir"
"delete_files" -> "closedir"
"delete_files" -> "opendir"
"delete_files" -> "DFL_ck_free"
"delete_files" -> "exit"
"delete_files" -> "rmdir"
"delete_files" -> "printf"
"delete_files" -> "fflush"
"delete_files" -> "unlink"
"delete_files" -> "strlen"
"delete_files" -> "DFL_ck_alloc"
}
```

I wouldn't mind spending a lot of RAM / time calculating this result, I'd just like it to look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the desired structure or layout of this graph, it's difficult to know what you would consider to be nice output. But with large graph with few ranks like this one, using the graph attribute `rankdir=LR` can improve the output significantly. You could also try experimenting with (cluster) subgraphs and the `splines` attribute.